# What is '+' in the permissions field mean?

Tags: unix, permissions

My professor needed access for copying my files and I used 'setfacl -b .' on my home directory to give him access. Now I changed it but now no one has access. So I then changed it so others can now have execute permission

When I look at all the users on my server though, everyone seems to have "drwxrwx--x+" while mines is only "drwxrwx--x" without the '+'. Can someone explain what that means? And how can I make mines like theirs?

Thanks.

Comment: Try this little snippet of (pseudo) code: AdminFactory.GetAdminInstance().Ask("When I look at all the users on my server though, everyone seems to have "drwxrwx--x+" while mines is only "drwxrwx--x" without the '+'. Can someone explain what that means? And how can I make mines like theirs?");

Comment: Shouldn't this be on ServerFault or perhaps SuperUser? This isn't a programming question. If that's what `Jas` was getting at, cute :P.

Answer (score 4):

The Plus sign means that there is an ACL in effect for that file.

Use the "getfacl" commands to view the ACLs that you want to copy and then setfacl to set them (make sure you understand what permissions you are granting first).

Comment: Is there a way where I can put ACL back into effect? I guess the commmand the professor gave me 'setfacl -b .' removed the ACL from my home directory. He just wanted to copy certain files.

Comment: It's running getfacl in my folder using 'getfacl -R .' on my home folder. How do I get the file to setfacl to?

Answer (score 1):

It's going to depend in part on the flavor of unix you're using. It often means that there are ACL rules applied to your directory.

Ref: http://sadiquepp.blogspot.com/2010/01/in-output-of-ls-l-stands-for-what.html

Answer (score 0):

The "+" indicates that there is an ACL (Access Control List) entry
associated with the file

See the documentation for `setfacl --restore`:

> Restore a permission backup created by 'getfacl -R' or similar. All permissions of a complete directory subtree are restored using this mechanism. If the input contains owner comments or group comments, and setfacl is run by root, the owner and owning group of all files are restored as well. This option cannot be mixed with other options except '--test'.

From the [setfacl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/setfacl) man page